# Query function behaving strange with dates in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Function which isn't working: =QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A WHERE B > " & D1, 0)

What it's looking at:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Strings | 13 Feb 2023 |
| Strings | 18 Feb 2023 |
| Strings | 21 Feb 2023 |

Cell D1 =
10 Feb 2023

Trouble shooting:
The query is coming up no results. All dates are numbers, when I format them as numbers instead of dates it works, when I format them as DD MMM, it works, but when I format them as DD MMM YYYY it doesn't work and this is the format I need it in.

Question
Why is Query so sensitive to date formats?? I always use different date formats depending on the sheet and vlookup has no issue with this. Also why on earth would it just not accept one format? I really want to learn for future

Answer (score 1):

for `query` you may use:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "SELECT A WHERE B > date'"&text(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

[image]

if you wish to avoid the `query` confusion; you may just go with simple `filter` Fx

```
=filter(A:A,B:B>D1)
```

[image]